# How do I remove the Dropbox entry from the Windows Explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, dropbox

To start, I have already uninstalled Dropbox from my system. However, as the title suggests, the navigation pane entry resides, rather annoyingly, and seems to be the cause for a slowdown in Windows Explorer's performance.

[image]

If I click the entry I get the standard resource unavailable message.

[image]

I have already searched for the issue and followed guides posted on [the dropbox forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/How-does-one-remove-the-Dropbox-link-from-the-Navigation-Pane-om/td-p/93970) and on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3fz8hf/how_to_removedelete_dropbox_from_left_panel_of/) and tried [this .Bat program](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/59830-add-remove-dropbox-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html) (thanks to @Yisroel Tech). None helped me solve the issue as the Registry Keys that they mention {E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} don't exist anymore (I assume, because its no longer installed).

I have also restarted the PC and separately, Windows Explorer, in my efforts.

Any other ways to remove the item from the Navigation Pane?

**EDIT:**

There aren't any options in the right click menu to remove the item.

I've now tried to add the key `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}` with a REG_DWORD of `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` and value of 0 to the locations
`HKCR\CLSID\`, `HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\` and `HKCU\Software\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\` to no effect.

I also tried searching the location `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\` for something relating to Dropbox but there isn't anything.

**Result:**

After using the answers below to find keys I came across a set of four keys labeled dropbox under `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-600964879-747821205-3265537649-1932` all of them ending in `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}`, so I'm not sure why they didnt turn up in my original searches but they were there.

Comment: What are the options when right-clicking the icon?

Comment: @YisroelTech added above.

Comment: Maybe try the Remove_Dropbox_from_navigation_pane.bat from here https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/59830-add-remove-dropbox-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @YisroelTech Thanks for the suggestion, but opening the bat in a text editor shows that it modifies the same Registry Key as the other tutorials, so unfortunately wont help here

Comment: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\ShellFolder and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} are not exactly the same.

Comment: You mention that you tried the {E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} keys, but that they are not there. Did you try to create it and set it the way the tutorials tell to do?

Comment: I have tried searching for both. I haven't tried creating it myself, I'll give that a go next :)

Comment: Also take a look if you can find anything Dropboxy in the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\

Comment: @YisroelTech no joy

Comment: What do you have in the NameSpace key? And how about the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace

Comment: @YisroelTech NameSpace key from earlier has just one entry for OneDrive and the second one has loads to do with OneNote, Hyper-V, ControlPanelHome, RecycleBin but nothing relating to Dropbox. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try also under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum` to add a key named `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1B}` with value 1. Check also leftovers using [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Dropbox, and then running the .bat? You could also try reinstalling, removing it from the navigation pane, and then uninstall Dropbox.

Comment: CCleaner has a tool to check for orphaned register entries, you can create a backup and fix said entries. Give it a try, works wonders for me on file extensions.

Comment: I would reinstall Dropbox as an Administrator, reboot the machine, then immediately uninstall Dropbox as an Administrator.  Do not use CCleaner, in the past it has distributed malware worm, and it doesn't do anything Add/Remove Program doesn't already do.  Registry cleaners are just plain dangerous.

Comment: I have observed the keys having different values between my computers. The last section varies, so just look for `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to go through the registry but not the way you did it. It should be done by changing the existing key, not by adding a new one. I had cases where the "CLSID"-Number didn't match (maybe due to the windows/Dropbox version, but I'm not 100% sure about it). If this is the case for you, try to find the right key/value first:

- In the registry try to locate `System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree` (search for `values`, not `keys` or `data` => see note at the bottom of my answer).

  [image]

  Make sure you start searching at the "root folder" (`Computer`).

  [image]
- You should find a registry key/value that looks like this:

  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}\System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree`

  [image]

  Depending on the software you have installed there will be somewhat around 20 or more in total. Make sure you got the one that belongs to Dropbox. Usually there should be some kind of "dropbox-reference" in the registry key. If you are unsure you can search for the CLSID on the internet, it's a unique global identifier.
- Change the `data` of the `System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree`-value to `0`

  [image]

**Make sure you don't just change the one you created yourself. There should already be one that has been created by the Dropbox installer. And make sure to change all the created keys for Dropbox (with the same CLSID-Number) not just the first one you find. You should find a second one within the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\`**

If Dropbox has been deinstalled the "data" should remain 0. There might be some process of Dropbox that still gets executed at startup and changes it back to 1. In this case you can remove access altogether to the CLSID-key (right click, choose permissions and select "access denied").

**Note:** In the registry....

- the "folders" are called `keys`
- the "entries" in the folders are called `values`
- the "values assigned to the entries" are called `data`

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that my answer is basically a duplicate of yours. I didn't realise it before I started writing my answer as I didn't fully read your answer first, but seeing as your answer presented itself to me as a 'wall of text', which I unfortunately didn't read before deciding to write an answer, and since I made screenshots and formatted it to be easier to read, I'm going to leave my answer up, and not delete it.

Comment: @3D1T0R that's ok, in turn I "borrowed" two of you're screenshoots because I only had German ones available. I assumed the OP had enough knowledge but you are right, it's better to add screenshots for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have DropBox installed, so I can't tell you exactly where to go, however from the other information here, we can tell that this item must have a registry key containing a value named `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` which is set to 1, so my recommendation is to search the registry for keys with that value:

1. Open Registry Editor
   [image: Open the Start menu and type "regedit", then press Enter]
2. Click on "Computer" at the top of the left panel
   This ensures that you're at the beginning of the search order.
   [image: Left panel of Registry Editor with "Computer", which is at the top of the list selected]
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or click Edit > Find...)
   [image: Registry Editor's "Edit" menu with "Find..." selected]
4. Type `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` in the input labeled "Find what:" and (since we know we're looking for the name of a value) make sure the checkbox next to "Values" is checked, and uncheck the checkboxes next to "Keys" and "Data" to make it search quicker, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click "Find Next")
   [image: Find dialog with "System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree" in the "Find what:" input, and "Keys" and "Data" unchecked, but "Values" checked]
5. You should find several values which are in unrelated keys. I don't recommend messing with them, as they are (at least most of them) part of Windows.
6. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> (or click "Edit > Find Next")
   [image: Registry Editor's "Edit" menu with "Find Next" selected]
7. At some point you should find one that says name of the entry you want to remove in the key's `(Default)` value
   As you can see, the one I've found that corresponds to something I have in my 'NameSpaceTree' is in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`. The circled part should say "Dropbox".
   [image: Somewhat anonymised registry key in "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID" which corresponds to an item pinned to the 'NameSpaceTree' on my computer]
8. Double click on `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree`, and in the dialog that appears, change `1` to `0`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click OK)
   [image: "Edit DWORD (32-bit) Value" window with "0" in the "Value data:" input]
9. Finally, Open up a new Windows Explorer window to see if it's gone. If it still shows up, go back to Step 6, as there may be multiple keys for it which should also be changed in the same way.

Comment: I gave the bounty to @Albin because he posted first but both of you helped in demonstrating the find tool to search for values of keys in the registry, thanks :)